# Very slow cURL request to same domain

Tags: php, performance, curl, localhost

I am calling an API with cURL to the same domain (right now its localhost) with the following code

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

It is very slow, (up to 7 seconds) unless I add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
```

I know its not simply the time it takes for the API to load, because if I request the API url in the browser, its almost instant.

How would you suggest troubleshooting this issue? Or should I not be using cURL at all?

Comment: Maybe a DNS problem? What is the content of $url ?

Comment: force ssl/https off for curl.

Comment: @Babblo an example of $url: $url='localhost/wpengine/?cat=1&json=t'

Comment: @Dave Could you explain why that would make a difference?

Comment: ...and why does adding CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT make any difference?